# Scrollview not scrolling with grid

Tags: android

I am having trouble getting my scrollview working. Have tried many settings on these views.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/noteImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/c4" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteImage">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteImage">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/csharp_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="C#" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dflat_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Db"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dsharp_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="D#" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eflat_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Eb"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="E" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fsharp_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="F#" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gflat_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Gb"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/g_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="G" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aflat_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="Ab"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/a_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/asharp_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="A#" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="B" />
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: LinearLayout is unnecessary!

Comment: The content of scrollview will not scroll if it does not exceed the height of your screen or its parent if any

Comment: I removed the linear layout and updated my question to reflect that. The gird view is halfway off the screen in the visual designer.